# How do I time a compound command executed in parallel?

Tags: bash, shell, background-process, time-utility

How do I time a compound command when most but not all commands executed in parallel:

For example the command:

```
comd1 ; comd2 & comd3 & comd4 & comd5 &
```

I tried

```
time (comd1…)
```

But from the output I can speculate that only `comd1` was timed because `comd2` to `comd5` usually are not so fast to finish executing when being executed alone.

Answer (score 5):

You could add a `wait` to wait for all background processes.

Examples:

```
$ time (sleep 1; sleep 2 & sleep 4 & wait)
real    0m5.007s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.005s

$ time (sleep 1; sleep 6 & sleep 4 & wait)
real    0m7.011s
user    0m0.005s
sys     0m0.003s
```